# Using Tailwind CSS, how do I make the width and height of a page always fit the screen?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS to design my website and I keep running into an issue while creating my layout: the page is always wider and taller than the size of the screen. If you've ever had this happen before, you know how annoying it is.

I think this is because I added a navbar with fixed positioning and `h-content`. In any case, my main wrapper `div` is supposed to wrap the entire page, fit the screen without creating any scrollbars, and have `m-8` margins on all sides, while still fitting the screen.

I'm finding that the height properties (`h-full`, `h-content`, `h-screen`) and width properties (`w-full`, `w-content`, `w-screen`) can be confusing at times. Especially when I start adding other divs to the page to create "sections" with specified heights and widths.

Does anyone have a good tutorial or article on how these properties work? I must not be understanding them properly.

I'm using React and Next.js. On the homepage, I am returning something like this:

```
<div className="w-screen h-screen">
    {/* This nav is applied to all pages through the pages/.app */} 
    <Navbar className="w-full h-content" />

    <div className="flex w-full h-full m-8">
        <section className="w-1/2" />
        <section className="w/1/2" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Any resources to help me understand how to build layouts using Tailwind would help tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in global css file (probably `styles/global.css`) before you can use w-full and h-full as they depend on container element's width and height.
In case of a page the container is most probably a div being used to render react. And that div depends on body, which depends on html tag.

```css
html, body, #ID_OF_THE_CONTAINER_DIV_IN_WHICH_REACT_IS_BEING_RENDERED {
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}
```

Also checkout https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles

Answer (score 0):

The video below really explains in detail how to create this kind of layout:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ1m4r3BqaY&ab_channel=WebBlocksApp

[And this is the example I created](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Ow445YYOoI?layout=horizontal). pay attention to the CSS tab. there are extra styles needed for this to work properly. Also notice I added extra height on purpose, but if you remove the class the content will still wrap the whole available space.